# query on shares

Tags: ratio

A person bought a share (par value is rs 50) at the rate 150 from market. If it gives20% dividend what is effective return?

Answer (score 0):

$20\%$ dividend on par value of $50$ is $10$. The effective return is $10$/$150$ or $6.67\%$, assuming there is no change in the market price.